# What method would I use for this proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Show there are no integer, $x$ and $y$, that satisfy $x^{2} + 3y^{2} = 8$. 
I have no idea where to start unfortunately or what kind of method to start off with.

Answer (score 4):

Some people call this a "proof by exhaustion". As noted earlier, $x$ must be between $-2$ and $2$ and $y$ has an even smaller range, so just try all the possible values for $x$ and $y$. Some of my students call this a "proof by Duh!".

Comment: Also "Brute Force Method".

Comment: @Felix We could give this post the new (self-referential) tag if we listed all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

What is the graph of this formula? Looking at the shape, there aren't a whole lot of integer candidates.